# Why do pyplot methods apply instantly and subplot axes methods do not?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I'm editing my graphs step by step. Doing so, `plt` functions from `matplotlib.pyplot` apply instantly to my graphical output of pylab. That's great.

If I address axes of a subplot, it does not happen anymore.
Please find both alternatives in my minimal working example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
sp1 = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
f.show()

# This works well
sp1.set_xlim([1,5])

# Now I plot the graph
df = pd.Series([0,5,9,10,15])
df.hist(bins=50, color="red", alpha=0.5, normed=True, ax=sp1)

# ... and try to change the ticks of the x-axis
sp1.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 15, 1))
# Unfortunately, it does not result in an instant change
# because my plot has already been drawn.
# If I wanted to use the code above,
# I would have to execute him before drawing the graph.

# Therefore, I have to use this function:
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 15, 1))
```

I understand that there is a difference between `matplotlib.pyplot` and an `axis` instance. Did I miss anything or does it just work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of pyplot functions (if not all) have a call to `plt.draw_if_interactive()` before returning. So if you do

```
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.xlim([-1,4])
```

you obtain that the plot is updated as you go. If you have interactive off, it won't create or update the plot until you don't call `plt.show()`.

But all pyplot functions are wrappers around corresponding (usually) `Axes` methods.

If you want to use the OO interface, and still draw stuff as you type, you can do something like this

```
plt.ion()  # if you don't have this, you probably don't get anything until you don't call a blocking `plt.show`
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # create an empty plot
ax.plot([1,2,3])  # create the line
plt.draw()  # draw it (you can also use `draw_if_interactive`)
ax.set_xlim([-1,4])  #set the limits
plt.draw()  # updata the plot
```

You don't have to use the pyplot you don't want, just remember to `draw`

Answer (score 1):

The `plt.xticks()` method calls a function `draw_if_interactive()` that comes from `pylab_setup()`, who is updating the graph. In order to do it using `sp1.set_xticks()`, just call the corresponding `show()` method:

```
sp1.figure.show()
```

Comment: `show` is blocking, when I use it from python. It's not blocking from ipython, but I guess is due to my settings. and `f.show()` it's enough